# Why char value assignment to float is not working

Tags: c

Note:This question is very simple but when I am searching in Google I haven't got any clear clarification.

I have following program

```
int main()
{
 float c;
 scanf("%f",&c);
 printf("%f",c);
}
```

o/p
when I am giving a `int` value (e,g - 9) it is showing it as 9.000000

but when I am giving char value like 'a' it is not showing and showing 0.000000.I know the `memory representation of float` is totally different from `int` but then how when I am giving `int value (9)` it is showing but when I am giving `char (a)` which is also an int (97) is not showing.

How it is happening. What is the memory representation during `char` assignment.

Comment: The title is indicative of your fundamental misunderstanding. There is no *assignment* of a `char` to a `float`. You're trying to *parse* an ASCII character 'a' using `scanf`'s floating point specifier. Terminology is key here.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Note that there are no `char`s here anywhere in your code.

This is the way [**`scanf`**](http://linux.die.net/man/3/scanf) is *supposed* to work. If you check the return value from `scanf` *(like you should be!)* you'll probably see that it's returning 0, meaning no items were matched.

When you give `scanf()` a `"%f"` format string, that means "I want you to try and get me a *floating point* number. When you provide input like 'a', it's not going to match anything, because `'a'` is not a valid floating-point number.

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/scanf/

Comment: Thanks for the clarification but when I am giving int then is that a valid float no.i saw the wiki for type conversion but there i saw when we assign a int to float the truncation will be the result but my case why the truncation is not going to happen.How a char is interpreted and how a int is interpreted by scanf.

Comment: @pradipta If you want to play around with type conversions, then just assign some values to variables, and then assign those variables to variables of other types. Leave `scanf` out of it - he's *only* going to parse input of the type you tell it to parse. *Do you understand the difference?* What you're seeing has nothing to do with datatype conversion or interpretation - only *parsing*.

Comment: But how it is taking int as int is not a float type.I saw the printing the return value and it is giving 0 when entering char value and returning when giving int value.But how it is taking int value when it is not matching to it.

Comment: What you do mean "taking"? Do you mean why is `9` a valid input for `"%f"`? If you read the [documentation](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/scanf/) you'll see that the decimal point and following digits are *optional*. Which means that `9` is valid for `"%f"`. There is no integer data in that case. Only your *decimal* input string, and the `float` variable.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.but how a char is interpreted ,I mean char is also integer so if I am giving 'a' it should be taking as 97 and from that its decimal input only taken that is 97.

Comment: @pradipta **No.** `scanf` deals with *strings* not *binary data*. 'a' is *not* 97, it is the letter 'a'. When you tell it `"%f"` it is *only* going to accept characters that make up a decimal number.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.I got some point here.I need to read the documentation.

Comment: If you want to see the behavior you describe, then do something like `char c = 'a';  printf("%d\n", c);` which will print "97". But please, leave `scanf` out of the equation if you just want to play with datatype conversions.

Comment: @WedaPashi Fair enough. Thanks for pointing it out. Now let us delete this mess of comments so we don't distract from the original discussion.

Answer (score 4):

First, you usually should end your `printf` format string with a newline `\n` or else call `fflush`.

Then, you should read the documentation on `scanf` i.e. its man page [scanf(3)](http://linux.die.net/man/3/scanf)

It can fail, and it returns the number of successful matches:

> Return Value
>
> These functions return the number of input items successfully matched
>   and assigned, which can be fewer than provided for, or even zero in
>   the event of an early matching failure.
>
> The value EOF is returned if the end of input is reached before either
>   the first successful conversion or a matching failure occurs. EOF is
>   also returned if a read error occurs, in which case the error
>   indicator for the stream (see ferror(3)) is set, and errno is set
>   indicate the error.

A failure is happening when you type an input letter `a` against a `%f` conversion specification. In your case the `c` variable is left unchanged (i.e. "uninitialized").

You should test the result of `scanf` (it is `<=0` on failure in your case).

Comment: But how it is taking int as int is not a float type.I saw the printing the return value and it is giving 0 when entering char value and returning when giving int value.But how it is taking int value when it is not matching to it.

Comment: @pradipta It *is* matching it. Again, `9` is a valid input for `%f`. See my comment, and read the documentation.

Comment: @pradipta And as Basile said, `c` is left unchanged - it still has the same value as before you called `sprintf` - it just happened to be zero.

Answer (score 1):

`scanf` in the form you wrote it will try to find and read numbers (`int`/`float`) up to the first non numerical character (newline, space, any letter). Letters are `int`s, but this is because of the `scanf` and the way it should behave. Read up the docs.

Comment: @pradipta I understand you're being polite, but there's no need to thank every individual answer. It just adds clutter to the site, and doesn't add anything to the discussion. If an answer is helpful, then show your appreciation by "upvoting" an answer, and finally accepting the best one.