# Switch Case working differently

Tags: c, char, switch-statement

Consider two codes. Why are they giving different outputs though same value hass been assigned to i ,'i' being a char in both the codes.

first code-->
(here value is assigned to i directly)

```
void main()
 {
  char i=3;

  clrscr();
  switch(i)
     {
      default : printf("\nHi..\n");
          break;
      case 1:printf("\na");
         break;
      case 2:printf("\nb\n");
        break;
      case 3:printf("\nc");
          break;
      }
  }
```

second using printf-scanf--->

```
void main()
 {
  char i;
  printf("ENTER i");
  scanf("%c",&i);
  clrscr();
  switch(i)
     {
      default : printf("\nHi..\n");
                break;
      case 1:printf("\n\na");
         break;
      case 2:printf("\nb\n");
        break;
      case 3:printf("\nc");
          break;
      }
 }
```

in the second code when i m giving 3 as input, i get "Hi.." as output. What makes the two codes work differently..??

Answer (score 1):

After reading the character from stdin:

```
scanf("%c",&i);
```

`i` will contain the ASCII code of 3 (51) and not the value 3, leading to taking the `default` branch of `switch`.

The solution is declaring your variable as `int` and using

```
scanf("%d",&i);
```

to read it.

In the first example you assigned to `i` the integer value `3`, which is not the same as assigning the character `'3'`. In C, when you assign a value to a `char` variable that value would represent a code specific to a certain character (considering a standard).

In the second example the `scanf` function read a character from `stdin`, which was interpreted as a character due to the use of `%c`, and assigned to the given variable the code specific to the read character.

Comment: ya i knw that... but why the value being alot to c in first code..is not treated as ASCII as in second case..though i have not used single inverted comma(') to signify a character..
why is their a differnce in the way in which c is assigned value..

Comment: @DD24: I completed my answer as a explanation.

Answer (score 1):

In the first you're using

```
char i = 3
```

But when you use scanf you essentially use:

```
char i = '3'
```

These two contain different values

See the following ASCII http://www.asciitable.com/

Answer (score 0):

It is not related to the switch statement, but to the `scanf` function.

Read its documentation ie [scanf(3)](http://linux.die.net/man/3/scanf) man page. See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17668811/841108) to a very related question.

Notice that the char `'3'` is not encoded as 3, but as 51 in [ASCII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII)

Learn to enable all warnings and debugging info (e.g. compile using `gcc -Wall -g`) and learn to use the debugger (i.e. `gdb`)

Comment: ya i knw that... but why the value being alot to c in first code..is not treated as ASCII as in second case..though i have not used single inverted comma(') to signify a character..
why is their a differnce in the way in which c is assigned value..

Comment: Please look, as I said, into [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17668811/841108)

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to

```
char i  -> int i;

scanf("%c",&i) -> scanf(" %d",&i);
```

Comment: ya i knw that... but why the value being alot to c in first code..is not treated as ASCII as in second case..though i have not used single inverted comma(') to signify a character..
why is their a differnce in the way in which c is assigned value..

Comment: You can change your first example to match the second example, by doing `char i='3';` instead of `char i=3;`